# How the 'conflict' between heart/feelings and the "head" was described in the classical period

Tags: passage-request, roman-culture

It sometimes happens to us, living beings of this age that we are, that we experience some kind of inner conflict; a conflict between what seems to our intellect or reason(*) and the feeling or "heart" as many would call it. An example would be a job that looks quite good on paper, but the individual decides to reject it finally, not necessarily because any specific reason he could pinpoint, but because it didn't "feel" right.

I am mostly interested in an account of the classical period that describes such an inner conflict (and it may quite board in range - something like acting against "conscience" even), and would be especially happy to find what are the entities in the conflict as "head/brain" and "heart". Originally I though that *ego* and *animus* could be good candidates for "head" and "heart" based on several quotes, but I have my seconds thought now.

---

(*) as much as we have one (or should I speak for myself). For genuine rational entity seems to be quite rare. It can be called many times "justificator" as it merely post-factum *used* to justify a decisions taken based on irrational causes (not that I'm saying this a bad thing).

Comment: Plato contrasted the "reasoning part" (λογιστικόν), spirit (θύμος), and desire (ἐπιθυμία), giving examples of how they come apart in the *Republic* (among other places). Aristotle also talks extensively about the relationship between reason and the passions, especially in *Nicomachean Ethics* VII. But perhaps you are looking for something in Latin?

Comment: @brianpck, thanks for that. well, I was more oriented in Latin (as I don't know any Greek), I wonder how those terms were translated in Latin of the classical period, but more interested in causal way of speaking rather than deep philosophical .  At any case this can constitute an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Cicero's *[De Re Publica, Book I](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0031%3Abook%3D1%3Asection%3D60)*, there's a conversation between Scipio and Laelius which deals with this sort of conflict:

> *S. Ergo non probares, si **consilio** pulso **libidines**, quae sunt innumerabiles, iracundiaeve tenerent omnia?*
>
> (Scipio. Then you would not approve that the evil passions, which are
> innumerable, should expel conscience, and that lusts and animal
> propensities should assume an ascendency over us?)
>
> *L. Ego vero nihil isto animo, nihil ita animato homine miserius ducerem.*
>
> (Laelius. For my part, I can conceive nothing more wretched than a
> mind thus degraded, or a man animated by a soul so licentious.)
>
> *S. Sub regno igitur tibi esse placet omnis **animi partes**, et eas regi **consilio**?*
>
> (Scipio. You desire, then, that all the faculties of the mind should
> submit to a ruling power, and that conscience should reign over them
> all?)
>
> *L. Mihi vero sic placet.*
>
> (Laelius. Certainly, that is my wish.)

On the one hand, the word that is here translated as "conscience" is *consilium*, which, according to *[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=consilio&la=la#lexicon)*, can also be translated as:

> As a mental quality, *understanding, judgment, wisdom, sense,
> penetration, prudence*

On the other hand, the words used in opposition to this higher faculty is *pars animi*, the parts of the mind (here translated as "faculties"), or *libido* (translated as "evil passions") which, according to *[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=libido&la=la#lexicon)*, can be translated as:

> *pleasure, desire, eagerness, longing, fancy, inclination*